# How NASM finds this label address?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, position-independent-code

I was wondering how NASM works with this piece of code:

Just let you know that it is loaded at 0x1000 by a bootloader, and the bootloader goes into protected mode (setup GDT with segments covering whole memory, setup segment registers...) before jumping to 0x1000 (this piece of code):

```
[bits 32]
[org 0x0]

jmp test

loop:
jmp loop

test:
mov byte [0xB8000], 'H'
mov byte [0xB8001], 0x57

end:
jmp end
```

When I compile this code in a separate file, how NASM knows the address of **test label** in memory to jump (it should be 0x1000 + difference in file)? Because it works but I don't understand how.

Comment: Your `org` directive is lying to the assembler: you're telling it that the code will be loaded starting at offset `0x0`, whereas you are actually loading it at offset `0x1000`.  But it won't matter here because `jmp test` is a relative jump: it only needs to know the *difference* in addresses between the end of the `jmp` instruction and the label `test`, which in this case is 2 bytes (the length of the `jmp loop` instruction that is in between).

Comment: `jmp` to a label uses *relative* jumps (`jmp rel8` or `jmp rel32` https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/jmp), so the code is position-independent.

Comment: So the assembler *does* think that label `test` is at offset `0x0004`.  But that information doesn't happen to play into the generated code in this case.  If you use `test` as an absolute address somewhere (`mov eax, test / jmp eax`) it will fail.